# Can you read from a lucene index while updating the index

Tags: lucene

I can't find a straightforward yes or no answer to this!
I know I can send multiple reads in parallel but can I query an index while a seperate process/thread is updating it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Lucene.  However, assuming you are talking about the Java version, the [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#head-6c56b0449d114826586940dcc6fe51582676a36e) has this to say:

#### Does Lucene allow searching and indexing simultaneously?

Yes. However, an IndexReader only searches the index as of the "point in time" that it was opened. Any updates to the index, either added or deleted documents, will not be visible until the IndexReader is re-opened. So your application must periodically re-open its IndexReaders to see the latest updates. The [IndexReader.isCurrent()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/api/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#isCurrent()) method allows you to test whether any updates have occurred to the index since your IndexReader was opened.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this :-)

Answer (score 2):

See also Lucene's near-real-time feature, which gives fast turnaround upon changes (adds, deletes, updates) to the index to being able to search those changes.  For example, using near-real-time you could make changes to the index and then reopen the reader every few seconds.